# JavaScript regex to capture everything after the second to last backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that looks like the following currently:

`/^.*[\\\/]/`

This will strip every single backslash from a string. The problem I'm facing is I have to now be able to capture everything from the second to last backslash.

Example:

`/Users/foo/a/b/c` would return `b/c`
`/Another/example/` would return `Another/Example`

So I need to capture everything after the second to last backslash. How would the regex above do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to get `a/b` from your first example if you're capturing everything around the second-to-last backslash? Not super-clear...

Comment: are your urls/strings consistently employing trailing slashes? or should they be ignored?

Comment: @haxxxton they can actually be ignored.

Comment: can we assume that the characters between the `/` are word characters (ie. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) are there other characters that need to be accommodated for (e.g. `$-_.+!*'(),`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with this simple solution:

```
s = "aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd";
s.split("/").slice(-2).join("/"); /* It will return "cccc/dddd" */
```

Comment: I think you mean `slice(-2)`. As `slice(2)` this will return too many items if `s = "aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee"` and too few if `s = "aaaa/bbbb/cccc"`

Comment: Good answer but you should remove any trailing slashes!

Comment: a wonderful example of why regex is overkill sometimes.  Illustrative of the power of `split` and `join`, AND `slice`.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean forward slash, not backslash.

Here is a regex alternative to pierlauro's answer.

```
/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/?$/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IPFj0y/1)

Answer (score 0):

As pierlauro's answer shows, `split`, `join`, and `slice` are probably the best options for this. But if you MUST use a regex (not sure why), you could employ something like the following:

[`\/?(\[^\/\]+?\/\[^\/\]+)\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/obB4ME/2)

This regex accommodates for optional trailing slashes and for urls shorter than 2 `/`s. It leverages the `$` character to focus our search scope on the end of the string.